# How to update a row with checking on NULL in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I need to update some columns in my table row. For this I write a stored procedure and there is key code below. I want to check that @Title or @Descriptions are not NULL and in this case update this data. What is a best practice for such situations?

```
UPDATE configuration
SET Title = @Title,
    Description = @Description, 
    ShowHeader = @ShowHeader,
    XmlConfiguration = @XmlConfiguration
WHERE Id = @Id
```

**EDIT:**

Let's imagine that the Title is not null but description is null. In this case I want to update only title and save the description without changes. Is it possible?

Comment: Can **one** of the two values be `NULL`?

Comment: @PM77-1 In the table the both variables are NOT NULL. But in the stored procedure I can put a NULL value, that will lead to an error. I want to check if title is not null and then update title, the same idea with description.

Comment: Please see my answer (below) that is slightly different than the other one and let me know which logic you had in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE configuration
SET Title = @Title,
    Description = @Description, 
    ShowHeader = @ShowHeader,
    XmlConfiguration = @XmlConfiguration
WHERE Id = @Id
AND (@Title IS NOT NULL OR @Descriptions IS NOT NULL)
```

For the new requirements:

```
UPDATE configuration
SET Title = @Title,
    Description = ISNULL(@Description,Description), 
    ShowHeader = ISNULL(@ShowHeader,ShowHeader),
    XmlConfiguration = @XmlConfiguration
WHERE Id = @Id
AND (@Title IS NOT NULL OR @Descriptions IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks! What if the Title is not null but description is null? In this case I want to update only title and save description without changes. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE configuration
SET Title = ISNULL(@Title,Title),
    Description = ISNULL(@Description,Description), 
    ShowHeader = @ShowHeader,
    XmlConfiguration = @XmlConfiguration
WHERE Id = @Id
```

> I want to check if title is not null and then update title, the same idea with description.

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to set the title column to the parameter's value only if the passed value isn't null, and perform similarly with the description column.

The above code will do this. If both @Title and @Descriptions are null, the values in the two corresponding columns will not change, but the other columns will still get updated. PM 77-1 and Lamak's answers will perform no update at all in the event that both @Title and @Descriptions are null.

Please note that the values will not change; however, the update statement will in fact write to the columns (namely, the current value). In terms of data integrity, this makes no difference, but it may be important in regards to auditing or change tracking considerations.

If you don't want to perform an update when both parameters are null, you can add a condition like this:

```
IF @Title IS NOT NULL OR @Descriptions IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    UPDATE configuration
    SET Title = ISNULL(@Title,Title),
        Description = ISNULL(@Description,Description), 
        ShowHeader = @ShowHeader,
        XmlConfiguration = @XmlConfiguration
    WHERE Id = @Id
END
```

Using an if block will force the server to evaluate your two parameter conditions first. If you put them in the where clause, it's possible (though unlikely) that the server will decide to check the @Id condition first. The above code saves a potential index seek in the case when both @Title and @Descriptions are null. This is, at best, a very minor savings, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this "trick".

If the update value is null, then use the ~original~ value.

```
Use Northwind
GO


 declare @City varchar(12)
  select @City = null

 Update [dbo].[Customers]
 Set
    [City] = ISNULL(@City, custs.City)
From
[dbo].[Customers] custs

where CustomerID = 'WOLZA'

Select City as MyCity, * from [dbo].[Customers] where CustomerID = 'WOLZA'


  select @City = 'WarszawaABC'

 Update [dbo].[Customers]
 Set
    [City] = ISNULL(@City, custs.City)
From
[dbo].[Customers] custs

where CustomerID = 'WOLZA'

Select City as MyCity, * from [dbo].[Customers] where CustomerID = 'WOLZA'
```